# Loop through a subset of an enum values

Tags: java, enums

I have an enum with 4 values, and I have a method signature that accepts an enum value. I would like to be able to do something with all enum values not passed as the argument to doSomething().

```
public void doSomething(EnumThing thing){
   EnumThing[] thingValues = EnumThing.values();
   List<EnumThing> valuesNotPassedAsArg = new ArrayList<EnumThing>();
   for(EnumThing th : thingValues){
       valuesNotPassedAsArg.add(th);
   }
   valuesNotPassAsArg.remove(thing);
  //here I would loop through all valuesNotPassAsArg and do something with them
}

public enum EnumThing{
 SOMETHING, SOMETHINGELSE, ANOTHERTHING;
}
```

Is there a cleaner way to do this? I feel as if the loop to get the items from the thingValues array is superfluous.

Comment: `EnumThing.values();` will return all the enum values, and not any kind of subset. So, what exactly do you want to do? Please explain a little bit more.

Comment: from all enum values I am removing the enum value passed as the argument, and then I would like to loop through the remaining values.

Comment: And I thought you already knew how to loop through an Array, or Collection.

Comment: So you want the list of the enums *excluding* `thing`?

Answer (score 29, accepted):

Look into `EnumSet`. Specifically,

```
import java.util.EnumSet;
import static java.util.EnumSet.complementOf;

for (EnumThing t : complementOf(EnumSet.of(thing))) {
  ... do the work ...
}
```

Answer (score 4):

@Marko's answer is better than this, but it might be helpful to know of this alternative way.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    EnumThing thing = EnumThing.ANOTHERTHING;

    List<EnumThing> list = new ArrayList<EnumThing>(Arrays.asList(EnumThing.values()));
    list.remove(thing);
    System.out.println(list);
}



public enum EnumThing{
    SOMETHING, SOMETHINGELSE, ANOTHERTHING;
}
```

This prints out

> [SOMETHING, SOMETHINGELSE]

Answer (score 2):

Another way is to use `Stream.of` method. For example:

```
public class EnumTest {

    public static enum MyEnum {
        VALUE1, VALUE2, VALUE3
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Stream.of(MyEnum.values()).filter(v -> v != MyEnum.VALUE2).forEach(System.out::println);
    }
}
```

Which prints:

```
VALUE1
VALUE3
```

Answer (score 1):

Looking at your title, to **iterate a range** you do

```
for (int i = YourEnum.___RANGE___START___.ordinal() +1; i != YourEnum.__RANGE___END___.ordinal() ; i++) {
    YourEnumvalue = YourEnum.values()[i];
    //use value
}
```

or this

```
for (YourEnum value: EnumSet.range(YourEnum.___RANGE___START___, YourEnum.__RANGE___END___)) {
    // use value
}
```

I you just want to skip a single element, then [Skip Head's solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14224149/1083704) might outperform the complementOf, which seems to be an overkill in case of single iteration.

Answer (score 0):

```
public void doSomething(EnumThing thing){
   EnumThing[] thingValues = EnumThing.values();
   for(EnumThing th : thingValues){
       if (th != thing) {
          doSomethingElse(th);
       }
   }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Something like this is a little bit better I'd say

```
public void doSomething(EnumThing thing){
   EnumThing[] thingValues = EnumThing.values();
   List<EnumThing> valuesNotPassedAsArg = Arrays.asList(thingValues);
   valuesNotPassAsArg.remove(thing);
   //here I would loop through all valuesNotPassAsArg and do something with them
}
public enum EnumThing{
   SOMETHING, SOMETHINGELSE, ANOTHERTHING;
}
```